# How to design navigation for WebView android?

Tags: android, webview

I want to design navigation for `WebView`

I have a `WebView` where I load HTML provided by the server with the following method.

```
 webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Let's say the initially loaded HTML is **Html1**.

Now the user can keep on refreshing this `WebView` which will keep on loading **Html1**. And I don't want to keep the user history.

But there are other navigation controls within **Html1**. On pressing of these controls, I load a completely different HTML (**Html2**) within that same `WebView`. In this case, I want to land user to **Html1** in case he presses back. So I want to design the navigation in such a way that I have control whether to keep user history or not per load.

So far I am not able to do so. Please let me know if there a solution for this problem.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "don't want to keep the user history," could you explain? By default, Android WebView should not add duplicate entries for page reloads.

Comment: If I am loading the same HTML again then webview will duplicate that item in the history.

Comment: If you're calling `loadDataWithBaseURL()`, then this is expected, right? If you just want to reload, why not call [`reload()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#reload())?